# Spark Dataset API groupByKey KeyValueGroupedDataset

Tags: apache-spark

How to create a TypedColumn in aggregate method after a groupByKey?
Supposing we had the following data structure and we created a bean (MyObject) to read the as dataset.

```
    USER | LIST | PARTNER_LIST

    Dataset<MyObject> r = sp.read()
    .parquet("mypath/*").as(Encoders.bean(MyObject.class));
    //group by list
    r.groupByKey((MapFunction< MyObject, String>) v -> 
    v.getList(), Encoders.STRING())
    .agg(TypedColumn<MyObject,R> what??? )
```

In the agg function i need to pass a TypedColumn but i find nothing online that explain how i can do it.

Can someone give me an example?

Answer (score 2):

As the name suggested, a TypedColumn is a column with Type.

- You can use `as[]` operator to add the type
- Also you can use `name()` method to add an alias.

A toy example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val exampleDF = Seq(("Bob", "male"), ("Mary", "female"), 
                    ("Mike", "male"), ("Mike", "male")).toDF("name", "gender")

exampleDF.groupByKey(_.getAs[String]("gender")).
  agg(countDistinct("name").as[Long].name("distinctCnt")).show()

+------+-----------+
| value|distinctCnt|
+------+-----------+
|female|          1|
|  male|          2|
+------+-----------+
```